# strace gets stuck at pause syscall

Tags: linux, strace

I have a program which launches a libmicrohttpd webserver (which manages its own threads), and then calls "pause" in the main thread so that the whole program doesn't exit.

I am trying to strace this program, but as soon as I get to the "pause" call, I don't get any further output from strace.  (Despite the fact that lots of IO, and hence system calls, are taking place in the background.)

Any suggestion how to fix this?  (I have tried `-e trace=\!pause` - but that just seems to suppress the output.  I still get the hang.

(If it matters, I am running on a debian derivative with kernel version 3.14.51.)

strace command: `strace -ttT -p 28948`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually that strace was only tracing calls in the main thread.  (It had nothing to do with `pause` - that was just the last syscall in the main thread.)

The fix is:

```
strace -ttffT -p 28948
```

(the documentation is not at all clear that `-ff` applies to multi-threaded as
well as multi-process applications.)